# how to trigger the button of the website when i press the enter key?

Tags: javascript, html

there is a button in a website ,i want to trigger the  button when i press enter key,
i write the javascript for the same but my script is works  suddenly for 2 or 3 second  and then again stop working i wont be getting any solution ,please help me for this.
i am using greasemonkey for this.
my javascript  is :

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Enter 2
// @namespace   www.irctc.co.in/eticketing/abubakar.js
// @description press enter to go payment area
// @include     https://www.irctc.co.in/eticketing/*
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownTextField, false);
function keyDownTextField(e)
{
   var keyCode = e.keyCode;
   if(keyCode==13)
   {
      document.getElementById("validate").click();
   }
   
}
```

**sorce code of button is:**

```html
<input id="validate" type="button" value=" Next ">
```

Comment: Your code works fine. Do you get any error on the console?

Comment: We'll need more details about your expected outcome in order to provide a proper answer.

Comment: my code is work well when i click on the outer area of the textbox and pressing the enter key , but i want to fill the captcha first in a textbox and press the enter key to trigger the button

Comment: is there any solution because i m injecting my js code in other website.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/theagitator/vtn4c0nj/

```
<input id="validate" type="button" value="Next" onclick='alert("yo")'>
```

Notice, that you have to first click somewhere in the result window to make it active before pressing the enter.

*This is not an answer, but I don't have enough reputation to comment on your question.*

Answer (score 0):

It could be that another element has focus, and is grabbing the key press. This can happen if there are multiple elements on a page that can be triggered by the Enter key.

As an alternative, if you set your input type to `submit`, the Return/Enter key will trigger that button without any JavaScript required, and it may solve your issue. If you only have one such input, you don't need to place it within a form element.

```
<input type="submit" id="validate" value="Next" onclick="doSomething();" />
```

Comment: my code is work well when i click on the outer area of the textbox and pressing the enter key , but i want to fill the captcha first in a textbox and press the enter key to trigger the button.       is there any solution because i m injecting my js code in other website and captcha is present on that website..

Answer (score -1):

Please try this code for captcha answer box :

```
<input id="target"
       class="text captcha-answer"
       type="text"
       autocomplete="off"
       maxlength="8"
       style="width:80px"
       name="j_captcha">
```

It should be work.